# Optimizing MySQL Database for wordpress

Tags: database, wordpress, optimization, database-administration

I am maintaining a blog with self hosted wordpress. For the last 5 months, my blog isn't really active as I hit "Server Error 500". The error says "The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout"

I seriously doubt that this is a server fault as I am running a very small database. But the technical support always says that I should optimize the database. My database is just 1.5 MB. I have installed a wordpress plugin to optimize the database. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer to "how do I make my website go faster" is well beyond the scope of an answer here - if I could be bothered writing down everything I know I'd probably publish it as a book.

However with such a small database, its very unlikely to be the database which is the source of the slowness here. If it were, then the cause should be evidence from the [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html).

Go check it.

Try running some 'hello world' scripts on the webserver - I suspect that might highlight any problems with the fastcgi daemon.

Comment: it was the problem with their web service. it's corrected at server side.